# Graphviz on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, installed-programs

I ran `apt-get install graphviz` which worked successfully and seems to be the official package.

Yet after installing I don't see graphviz in the list of installed programs, I also tried the command `graphviz` but nothing is found.

Is there a problem with this package? How can I open the GUI for graphviz?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy graphviz` and `dpkg -L graphviz | grep bin` to the question. Do you expect GVEdit to be installed?

Comment: What makes you think there is a GUI? Have you looked at the [documentation](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/documentation/)?

Comment: Whatever GUI programs are bundled with graphviz are completely useless.

Comment: @Elias that was my mistake I was thinking graphviz was a GUI based application

Comment: For those who had the same assumption about graphviz, there are several DOT file viewers. One is `sudo apt install xdot` then `xdot my-file.dot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

graphviz package contains the command-line tools, and whatever GUI programs are bundled with graphviz are completely useless. There's no way to get anything done in graphviz except with code. Because graphviz uses the built-in dot programming language which is included in the graphviz package, the source code of the graph or diagram is editable in any text editor. I use Gedit to edit dot code. What's nice about graphviz is it makes real sharp, nice looking computer generated charts and diagrams.

If you want to try an alternative to graphviz that runs natively in Ubuntu, take a look at draw.io desktop application for creating diagrams.
draw.io is a full scale GUI diagram making application and it is easier to use than Dia and other lightweight diagram making applications. The drawio snap package can be installed in all currently supported version of Ubuntu with this command:

```
sudo snap install drawio
```

What's nice about draw.io is that everything on the canvas can be moved with the mouse exactly where you want it without fiddling with changing changing a lot of numbers and then running the dot script to see if it looks good.

[image]

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 users, you can install draw.io via the native snap package manager via
`sudo snap install drawio` then just run `drawio`